# Zeros of polynomials as a finite union of manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Consider a polynomial in $d$ variables, $p:\mathbb{R}^{d}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Denote by $\mathcal{C}$ its set of zeros, i.e.
$$\mathcal{C}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{d}\ |\ p(x)=0\}.$$

> **Q.** Is it possible to find finitely many (not necessarily disjoint) manifolds $M_{1},\dots, M_{n}\subset\mathbb{R}^{d}$, with possibly different dimensions, such that
>   $$\mathcal{C}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}M_{k}?$$

My question arises in the context of degenerate real matrices, namely, the case where $\mathcal{C}$ consists on the set of symmetric real matrices with at least one repeated eigenvalue (in this context, $p(x)$ is the discriminant of the symmetric real matrix $x$). Any suggestion on how to approach this problem or a reference related to the problem will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is *yes*.

Your set $\mathcal{C}$ is by definition a [(semi)algebraic subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set) of $\mathbb{R}^d$, and any such a subset has a [Whitney stratification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_conditions) with finitely many (semi)algebraic strata.

See A. Dimca, *Singularities and Topology of Hypersurfaces*, [ZBL07535700](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0753.57001), 
Chapter 1, Corollary 1.12 for more details.

**Edit.** It is also true that any closed analytic (or subanalytc) set of an analytic manifold admits a Whitney stratification whose strata are analytic submanifolds. In the complex setting, this is called a *complex Whitney stratification*. See

M. Tib$\check{\rm u}$ar, *Polynomials and vanishing cycles*, Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics **170** (2007), [ZBL1126.32026](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1126.32026), page 219 and the references given therein.

Comment: Note however that the wikipedia reference that you provide contains a big mistake. If $X$ is a singular variety, the collection $Sing(X), Sing(Sing(X)),...$ is not a Whitney stratification in general.

Comment: @Libli: you are right. This does not define in general a Whitney stratification, but some refinement will, see J. L. Verdier, *Stratifications de Whitney et theoreme de Bertini-Sard*, Invent. Math. **36** (1976), 295-312. Thank you for the remark.

Comment: Please, what happens if we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Whitney stratification still exist in the complex setting. See my edit to the answer.